# Following groups when value is not null bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new in bigquery. I would like to increase group number when value in other column is not null. Example is in screenshot.
[Here is screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYceP.png) For example, conversion_time is null, so first group number is 0, same in second row. In third row, conversion time is not null, so group number increase by 1. In fourth row conversion time is null so group number stays 1 etc. I would be thankful for any help what function should I use.

#edit
Here is sample code:

```
SELECT

  fullVisitorId,
  session_id,
  start_time,
  campaign,
  conversion,
  IF(conversion=1, start_time, NULL) as conversion_time,
  0 as group_name --Here should be different group names after conversion is not null

    FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      trafficSource.source as source,
      trafficSource.campaign as campaign,
      hits.transaction.transactionId as transactionId,
      hits.eCommerceAction.action_type as action_type,
      CONCAT(IF(totals.visits = 1, fullVisitorId, NULL), CAST(visitId AS STRING)) as session_id,
      DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime), 'Europe/Warsaw') as start_time,
      IF(hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL AND hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '6',1,0) as conversion

      FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170101`,
      UNNEST (hits) as hits) ORDER BY fullVisitorId, start_time, conversion
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the other columns in your table so we can understand more what is the ordering logic for the conversion_time column

Comment: @XavierHAMIDA Thank you for your answer, I just added example code

Comment: Window function: `sum(IF(conversion=1 and start_time is not null, 1,0)) over (order by start_time) as group_name`  may be also `over (partition by fullVisitorId order by start_time)`